# comparing against a string

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript code that creates a different message depending on various factors in the response object from an Ajax request. For example

```
if (response.correct_guess === true){
    message = "your guess was correct
 }
```

If the user wins the game, the 'won' key is set to 'won'

```
won: "won"
```

and I'm therefore hoping to set the message like this

```
else if(response.won === "won") {
          message = "You finished with" + response.seconds + "left on the clock."
```

However, this 'else if' isn't getting triggered

I also tried "==" (i.e. two equal signs instead of three). Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Winning and guessing correctly are mutually exclusive in your code, which is not what you want. Guessing correctly causes winning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code means:

```
if (response.correct_guess === true){
    message = "your guess was correct

}else if(response.won === "won") {
      message = "You finished with" + response.seconds + "left on the clock."
}
```

*If* the guess is correct, `message = "your guess was correct`, and that's it. If the guess was not correct, AND if the user won, `message = "You finished with" + response.seconds + "left on the clock."`

You forget that if control enters the first if, it will never reach the second else if. In an if-elseif chain, the first if/elseif block control enters is the *only* one it will enter . I don't think you want that. You probably want:

```
if (response.correct_guess === true){
    message = "your guess was correct

}
if(response.won === "won") {
      message = "You finished with" + response.seconds + "left on the clock."
}
```